# Python string formatting from list after completed for loop

Tags: python, sql, string, formatting

I am building a sql query from several lists and dictionaries of variables. Currently I format each string within the for loops like this:

```py
for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
    for gk, gv in GENDER_MAP.items():
        for ak, av in AGE_MAP.items():
            query += line_a.format(plat=plat, gv=gv, av=av, ak=ak)
            query += line_b.format(plat=plat, gv=gv, av=av, ak=ak)
            query += line_c.format(plat=plat, gv=gv, av=av, ak=ak)
```

where lines a, b, and c are strings that need to be formatted with platform, gender, and age variables.

Instead of formatting these lines within the for loop, I would like to build the parameterized query, and then format later. How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't do string formatting to create a query. You should pass the parameters as a separate argument to `cursor.exec()`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have been asked to do it this way.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do it with named formatting placeholders, since you use the same names in each line.

Comment: yes, I thought as much.

Comment: If you use `{}` instead of `{variable}`, you can simply concatenate the parameter lists.

Comment: So once the empty {} are in place, how would I format them in the correct combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formatting placeholders to `{}` rather than variable names. Then concatenate the parameters to the format list (make sure they're in the proper order).

```
params = []
query_fmt = ""
for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
    for gk, gv in GENDER_MAP.items():
        for ak, av in AGE_MAP.items():
            query_fmt += line_a + line_b + line_c
            params += [plat, gv, av, ak] * 3

query += query_fmt.format(params)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.